# Is this Lagrangian function correct?

Tags: convex-optimization

I am trying to formulate the Lagrangian function for the following problem and constraints:
$$f(x,y,z)=  \sum_{n=1}^N x_{nk}\log(1+y_{nk})+\sum_{m=1}^Mz_{mk}C,$$
and maximize $\sum_{k=1}^Kf(x,y,z)$ subject to$$f_k(x,y,z)\geq b_k,\forall k,\ \sum_{k=1}^K\sum_{n=1}^N y_{nk}\leq Q,\ \sum_{k=1}^K z_{mk}\leq1,\forall m,\ z_{mk}\geq0, \forall k,m.
$$

Is the Lagrangian function for the above problem given below correct?
\begin{align*}
L(x,y,z,\lambda,\nu,\mu_1,\mu_2)&=\sum_{k=1}^Kf(x,y,z)+\sum_{k=1}^K\lambda_k(f_{k}(x,y,z)-b_k)\\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} +\nu\left(Q-\sum_{k=1}^K\sum_{n=1}^Ny_{nk}\right)+\sum_{m=1}^M\mu_m\left(1-\sum_{k=1}^Kz_{mk}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^K\sum_{m=1}^M\mu_{mk}z_{mk}.
\end{align*}

Comment: You seem to have two uses of the subscript $k$ that are throwing you off. The function $f$ is a _sum_ over the $K$ entries of $x$, $y$, and $z$. Presumably you mean for all $K$ values of $z$ to be nonnegative, but you have no summation for those. And why is there only one value of $b_k$ as well?

Comment: So I'd say that you need to fix your constraints so that you understand how many you actually have---I'm guessing $2K+2$---and then I suspect your Lagrangian will follow.

Comment: Yes you are right this $z_k \geq 0,\forall k$. $b_k$ is same for all $k=1....K$

Comment: Then you need a separate Lagrange multiplier for each nonnegativity constraint.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I edit the problem. Can you please check it. I am really obliged.

Comment: I'm still not convinced you're doing what you intend with $f(x,y,z)\geq b_k$. There's no need for $K$ separate constraints. What you have written is equivalent to $f(x,y,z)\geq \max_k b_k$.

Comment: Or do you have $k$ separate functions $f_k$? If so you haven't indicated that properly.

Comment: This is the first constraint $ \sum_{n=1}^N x_{nk}\log(1+y_{nk})+\sum_{m=1}^Mz_{mk}C\geq b_k, \forall k$. Yes I have $f_k$ separate functions.

Comment: That's still not notationally correct. $f(x,y,z)$ is a single function. If you have $K$ functions you have to have $K$ names.

Comment: Then what should be the correct format

Comment: Just call the $k$th function $f_k$.

Comment: you mean the second term will become like this $\sum_{k=1}^K \lambda_{k}(f(x,y,z)_{k}-b_{k})$

Comment: @MichaelGrant   $f(x,y,z)_k \geq b_k, \forall k$ should be the constraint. This is what you mean?

Comment: You _really_ need to learn some basic notation here. The functions should be $f_k(x,y,z)$, not $f(x,y,z)_k$.

Comment: ohh I am so sorry. you are right. Thank you so much